# AngularJS object keeps over-writing and wont push

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have the following AngularJS below which opens up a dialog and I type into 2 input fields and press `ok()` which will write the values of the inputs to my `$scope`.

This works but when I open the modal again and enter more details into the input fields and click `ok()` I am trying to add this to the current `input` object in my `$scope` but instead it is just over-writing it.

```
var theApp = angular.module('theApp', []);
var app = angular.module('theApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);



app.controller('MenuSideController', ['$scope','$modal','$log', function($scope, $modal, $log) {
    var ModalInstanceCtrl;

    $scope.createmarker = function () {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'template/modal-add-marker.html',
            controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
            resolve: {},
            scope: $scope.$new()
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
        }, function () {
            $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
    };
    ModalInstanceCtrl = function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
        $scope.input = [];
        $scope.ok = function () {
            $modalInstance.close($scope.input);
            console.log($scope);
            $scope.gps = "";
            $scope.title = "";
        };

        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
        };
    };


    $scope.plotmarkers = function($scope) {
        console.log($scope);
    };
}]);
```

[image: Angular Scope]

Check out my code in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/oYqDTtu4CaG5Htkj0jut?p=preview)

Comment: Please show what is `current input object in my $scope`? Or better post code example in Fiddle/Plunker

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/oYqDTtu4CaG5Htkj0jut?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add/change to `modalInstance`:

```
modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
     $scope.keys.push({title: selectedItem.titley, gps:selectedItem.gps, desc:selectedItem.desc});
    }
```

Demo <kbd>**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3awMNQeZQybg6s9fp58v?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You are just using the reference address to the value, if you use angular.copy(your-object) it will create a new instance that will not be overridden when you reopen the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think what you're trying to do is have the modal push selections into an array in the parent controller? If so, you simply need to change your `modalInstance.result.then` function to something like this

```
var ModalDemoCtrl = function ($scope, $modal, $log) {

  $scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  $scope.selected = {};
  $scope.selected.items = [];

  $scope.open = function () {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
      $scope.selected.items.push(selectedItem);
    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
  };
};
```

For a full working example, see here: http://plnkr.co/edit/IA8qTX29DDIS1jXqx3gw?p=preview

Comment: This is sort of what I am after but instead I wish to have input boxes which push to the $scope